# While import from excel, + sign is not inserted in number field, django

Tags: python, django, excel

I have one excel file which has SMS-no and WhatsApp-no fields. We are storing numbers with country codes in our database. While importing .xls file number is inserted successfully but the '+' sign is not inserted in the database.

I am sharing a screenshot of the excel file and how it is stored in a database.

`Screenshot of excel file`
[image]

`Screenshot of value store in DB`

[image]

`Add contact option`

[image]

`Data store in DB through Add Contact option`
[image]

Here is my code of views.py

```
                fs = FileSystemStorage()
                filedata = fs.save("ImportDB.xls", myfile)
                BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(
                    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
                filepath = BASE_DIR + "\media\ImportDB.xls"
                book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)
                sheet = book.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")
                database = MySQLdb.connect(
                    host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="mbs")
                cursor = database.cursor()
                query = """INSERT INTO addcontact (f_name, l_name, add_ln1, add_ln2, country, city, zip, sms_no, whtsp_no) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
                for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
                        f_name = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
                        l_name = sheet.cell(r, 1).value
                        add_ln1 = sheet.cell(r, 2).value
                        add_ln2 = sheet.cell(r, 3).value
                        country = sheet.cell(r, 4).value
                        city = sheet.cell(r, 5).value
                        zip = sheet.cell(r, 6).value
                        sms_no = sheet.cell(r, 7).value
                        whtsp_no = sheet.cell(r, 8).value
                        values = (f_name, l_name, add_ln1, add_ln2, country, city, zip, sms_no, whtsp_no)
                        cursor.execute(query, values)
                cursor.close()
                database.commit()
                database.close()
                fs.delete(filedata)
```

Every data is inserted successfully. But number added without + sign in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted data in string and concate + sign, but after concating it is appending .0 in each, number, So I used the split function and only get the value before. (dot).

here is my code

```
sms_no =  sheet.cell(r, 8).value
whtsp_no = sheet.cell(r, 9).value
sms1 = "+"+str(sms_no)
smsno = sms1.split(".")
finalsms = smsno[0]
whtsapp1 = "+"+str(whtsp_no)
whtsapno = whtsapp1.split(".")
finalwhtsap = whtsapno[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change field from some `IntegerField` to `ChardField`. Database treats integer `+123` as simply positive number `123`.

Comment: I already store it as a `CharField`, I have two options in my project, 1) is through import and 2) manually insert data one by one. And in the 2nd option, it is store + sign successfully. But it problem occurs only while importing. I am attaching another screenshot so you can understand easily.